# Pivoting a Pandas data frame from long to wide

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot-table

I have this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47152692/4399016):

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('aaaabbbc'), 'B': np.random.choice(15, 8)})
df2

   A   B
0  a   0
1  a  11
2  a   2
3  a  11
4  b  10
5  b  10
6  b  14
7  c   7
```

The expected should look something like

```
      a     b    c
0   0.0  10.0  7.0
1  11.0  10.0  NaN
2   2.0  14.0  NaN
3  11.0   NaN  NaN
```

The code solution provided online is as follows:
STEP 1:

```
df2.insert(0, 'count', df2.groupby('A').cumcount())
df2

   count  A   B
0      0  a   0
1      1  a  11
2      2  a   2
3      3  a  11
4      0  b  10
5      1  b  10
6      2  b  14
7      0  c   7
```

Step 2:

```
df2.pivot(*df2)
# df2.pivot(index='count', columns='A', values='B')

A         a     b    c
count
0       0.0  10.0  7.0
1      11.0  10.0  NaN
2       2.0  14.0  NaN
3      11.0   NaN  NaN
```

In my case I have a DATE column which has duplicate values. In count column, even though the cumcount method generates duplicates, this pivot works. But in my case, the Date Index column does not allow Pivot. Is it possible to perform Pivot with DATE column in spite of duplicate values?

```
       count       A   B
0      2023-01-01  a   0
1      2023-02-01  a  11
2      2023-03-01  a   2
3      2023-04-01  a  11
4      2023-01-01  b  10
5      2023-02-01  b  10
6      2023-03-01  b  14
7      2023-01-01  c   7
```

This Long form has to be made Wide with Count[DATES] as the first column and the values of Column A be made different Columns themselves. The Values of Column B populating the Pivot Table. Similar to this table below.

```
   A            a     b    c
count
2023-01-01     0.0  10.0  7.0
2023-02-01     11.0 10.0  NaN
2023-03-01     2.0  14.0  NaN
2023-04-01     11.0  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Why don't you provide the exact example **that doesn't work**?

Comment: I will edit. Downloaded the data using APIs. So its complicated.

Comment: Provide a **minimal** example, just enough to replicate your issue/error.

Comment: I'm reading `DateIndex`, and that's not a column. In which case, do `df2.set_index(cumcount_series, append=True)['B'].unstack(level=-1)`. Again, this is a guess, would need the sample data for more details.

Comment: I have edited to include sample data with valid values.

Comment: If the A is replaced by Date, the Date column values becomes the Column heading. And the 'A' Column values are nowhere to be found. I need unique sorted DATES as the first column and the values in Column 'A' as the various Column Headers.

Comment: Looks like a direct pivot: `df.pivot(index='count', columns='A', values='B')`. And if really you have duplicates: `df.assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby(['count', 'A']).cumcount()).pivot(index=['count', 'n'], columns='A', values='B')`

Comment: This works, but there is an additional column with values 0,1. Would you like to explain below in the answer section. Exactly what has happened?

Comment: For every Date value, there are 2 rows available here. But there can be only one right?